# Airflow Web UI do not reflect changes When Running Airflow for the First Time

Tags: airflow

I have installed Airflow 2.7.1 on my WSL environment and I'm facing an issue when accessing the Airflow web UI for the first time. Upon initial installation, I encountered the following messages, and they persist even after running 'airflow scheduler':

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMnPs.png)

Despite changing the executor to LocalExecutor and connecting to a MySQL database, I'm still encountering these three messages. Is there an issue with the connection to the web UI?

I'd appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue.

Airflow Functioning Properly

Comment: This question is about configuring airflow, not about programming or software development. Therefore you have to ask this question on airflow's support forum, not here on SO.